# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}{\frac{\ln\left(1+3^x\right)}{\ln\left(1+2^x\right)}}$

Tags: limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

> Prove the following limit without using approximations and derivatives: $$\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}{\frac{\ln\left(1+3^{x}\right)}{\ln\left(1+2^{x}\right)}}=0$$

I cannot think of any possible factorization or inequality (so that I could use the Squeeze Theorem) that doesn't use derivatives so as to find this limit. Any hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{z}{z+1} \le \log (1+z)\le z \tag 1$$

for $z>-1$.  Then, use the squeeze theorem.

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted region to reveal the solution.

> Using $(1)$, we have $$\frac{3^x}{2^x(1+3^x)}<\frac{\log (1+3^x)}{\log (1+2^x)}<\frac{3^x(1+2^x)}{2^x}\tag 2$$As $x\to -\infty$ both the left-hand and right-hand sides of $(2)$ approach $0$.  Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, the limit of the sequence of interest goes to $0$.

---

**NOTE 1:**

We can prove the inequalities in $(1)$ using
standard tools, which don't require the use of derivatives.  We need only to note that

$$e^x\ge 1+x \tag 2$$

For $x>-1$, we take the log of both sides to reveal

$$\log(1+x)\le x$$

which is the right-hand side inequality of $(1)$.  Likewise, if we make the substitution $x=-z/(z+1)$ in $(2)$, we obtain

$$e^{-z/(1+z)}\ge 1-\frac z{z+1}=\frac1{z+1}$$

whereupon rearranging yields for $z>-1$

$$\log(1+z)\ge \frac{z}{z+1}$$

as was to be shown.

---

**NOTE 2:**

We can prove the inequality given in $(2)$ using the limit definition of $e^x$

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$

I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), without the use of derivatives, that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is a monotonically increasing function of $n$ (If $x<0$, this is true for $n>|x|$).  Then, we have

$$e^x\ge \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\ge 1+x$$

where this last inequality follows from [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).  And we are done!

Comment: (1) is not known by theory we have until now, so I cannot use it without proving it. But it is proven only with the use of derivatives, so I cannot "officially" prove it...

Comment: One does not need differential or integral calculus to prove those inequalities.

Comment: I lost you, after "an increasing function of n". How do you conclude the following using monotony? $$e^x\geq \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) ^n$$

Comment: @Jason You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And thank you for the "best vote!"  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 7):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\ln(1+3^x)}{\ln(1+2^x)}$$
substituting $x=-t$, we get
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+3^{-t})}{\ln(1+2^{-t})}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to \infty}\left(\frac{\frac{\ln(1+3^{-t})}{3^{-t}}}{\frac{\ln(1+2^{-t})}{2^{-t}}}\right)\times \frac{2^t}{3^t}$$

$$=\left(\frac{\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+3^{-t})}{3^{-t}}}{\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+2^{-t})}{2^{-t}}}\right)\times\lim_{t\to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^t$$
$$=\frac{1}{1}\times (0)=\color{red}{0}$$

Comment: How do you know the $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}$ without derivatives? I think it cannot be used...

Comment: @Jason $$\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\frac{du}{1+u}\implies\frac{x}{1+x}\leqslant\ln(1+x)\leqslant x\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\cdots$$

Comment: @Did You are using integrals. We haven't even be taught "officially" derivatives, so integrals are a bit...

Comment: @Jason Quote: "Prove the following limit without using approximations and derivatives".

Comment: @Did Those are the bounds that I used in my answer and I obtained them quickly using the identical approach as you "Did" (sorry for the superfluous pun).  After the OP requested, I provided a way forward to establish those bounds without appealing to differential or integral calculus.  But, I agree with you ... the quote was explicit.

Comment: @Dr.MV Indeed. The substitution $x=−z/(z+1)$ is nice, I did not know that.

Comment: @Did I derived it yesterday while I was working out at the gym.  I was not aware of this either.  In fact, I backed into it through a couple of successive substitutions.  Anyway, thank you for the "nice" comment.  You are one of the "strongest " members that I have encountered since joining in late February.  So, a comment like that really means a lot to me!