# Evaluate the limit without using the L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+\sin(x)}-1}{\ln(1+\tan(x))}$$

How to evaluate the limit of this function without using L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: **Hint:** Use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for the numerator, and the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) for the denominator.

Comment: **Or**: multiply and divide by $\tan x$. Recall the limit of $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$, and recall the definition of a derivative.

Comment: I got $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{5}-1}{tgx}$$   what now?

Comment: You mean $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+\sin x)^\frac{1}{5}-1}{tgx}$. now, $\frac{1}{\tan x}=\cos x \frac{1}{\sin x}$. the cosine goes to 1, and for the sine make a substitution. what is, by definition, the derivative of $x^n$ at 1?

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor's developments at order $1$ and compose them:
\begin{align*}&\left.\begin{array}{l}
\sin x=x+o(x)\\\sqrt[5]{1+u}=1+ \dfrac15u+o(u)
\end{array}\right\}\Rightarrow\enspace\sqrt[5]{1+\sin x}-1= 1+ \frac15x+o(x)-1=\frac15x+o(x)\\[1ex]
&\left.\begin{array}{l}
\tan x=x+o(x)\\\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)
\end{array}\right\}\Rightarrow\enspace\ln{1+\tan x}= x+o(x)
\end{align*}
whence
$$\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+\sin x}-1}{\ln(1+\tan x)}=\frac{\dfrac15x+o(x)}{x+o(x)}=\frac{\dfrac15+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to \frac15.$$

Comment: This is the approach that I would use.  But, I thought that I would post another way forward that circumvents the use of L'Hospital's Rule, asymptotic analysis, or other derivative-based methodologies.  Instead, I relied on just basic inequalities and the squeeze theorem.  I would like to hear your thoughts if you have time.

Answer (score 2):

I thought that it would be instructive to present a way forward that circumvents the use of L'Hospital's Rule, asymptotic analysis, or other derivative-based methodologies.  To that end, herein, we use some basic inequalities and the squeeze theorem.

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837) for $x>-1$, I showed

$$\frac{x}{x+1}\le\log (1+x)\le x \tag 2$$

using only Bernouli's Inequality and the limit definition of the exponential function.

And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/75151#75151), the inequality

$$|x\cos x|\le |\sin x|\le |x| \tag 1$$

was established by appealing to geometry only.

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have for $x>0$

$$\frac{(1+x\cos x)^{1/5}-1}{\tan x}\le\frac{(1+\sin x)^{1/5}-1}{\log (1+\tan x)}\le\frac{(1+x)^{1/5}-1}{\frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x}} \tag 3$$

Note that the right-hand side 0f $(3)$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(1+x)^{1/5}-1}{\frac{\tan x}{1+\tan x}}& =(1+\tan x)\left(\frac{x\cos x}{\sin x}\right)\\\\\
&\times \left(\frac{1}{1+(1+x)^{1/5}+(1+x)^{2/5}+(1+x)^{3/5}+(1+x)^{4/5}}\right)\\\\
&\to \frac 15\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 0 
\end{align}$$

Similarly, the left-hand side 0f $(3)$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(1+x\cos x)^{1/5}-1}{\tan x}& =(\cos^2 x)\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)\\\\
&\times \left(\frac{1}{1+(1+x\cos x)^{1/5}+(1+x\cos x)^{2/5}+(1+x\cos x)^{3/5}+(1+x\cos x)^{4/5}}\right)\\\\
&\to \frac 15\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 0 
\end{align}$$

Therefore, by the squeeze theorem

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{(1+\sin x)^{1/5}-1}{\log (1+\tan x)}=\frac15$$

A similar development for $x<0$ results in the same limit.  Therefore, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+\sin x)^{1/5}-1}{\log (1+\tan x)}=\frac15}$$

and we are done without using anything other than standard inequalities!

Comment: That's tricky! I wonder if one can show $\mathrm e^x$ is convex directly without derivatives from the limit definition. Proving $\;\mathrm e^{\frac{x+y}2}\le \dfrac12(\mathrm e^x+\mathrm e^y)$ would be enough.

Comment: @Bernard Perhaps, but it isn't clear how the concavity alone of the log function is sufficient to provide the bounds that permit the "squeeze" of the limit of interest herein.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be made formal...

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+\sin(x)}-1}{\ln(1+\tan(x))}$$

---

$$\sqrt[5]{1+x} = 1 + \dfrac x5 - \dfrac{2}{25}x^2 + O(x^3)$$

$$\sqrt[5]{1+\sin(x)}-1 \approx \dfrac 15 \sin x - \dfrac{2}{25}\sin{x^2}$$

---

$$\ln(1+x) = x - \dfrac 12x^2 + O(x^3)$$

$$\ln(1+ \tan x) \approx \tan x - \dfrac 12 \tan^2 x $$

---

\begin{align}
   \frac{\sqrt[5]{1+\sin(x)}-1}{\ln(1+\tan(x))} 
   & \approx 
     \frac{\dfrac 15 \sin x-\dfrac{2}{25}\sin{x^2}}{\tan x-\dfrac 12 \tan^2 x} \\
   & \approx 
     \frac{\dfrac 15 \sin x-\dfrac{2}{25}\sin{x^2}}{\tan x-\dfrac 12 \tan^2 x} \\
   & \approx
     \dfrac{\sin x}{\tan x}
     \frac{\dfrac 15 - \dfrac{2}{25}\sin x}{1 - \dfrac 12 \tan x} \\
   & \approx
     \cos x \,
     \frac{\dfrac 15 - \dfrac{2}{25}\sin x}{1 - \dfrac 12 \tan x} \\
   & \to \dfrac 15 \quad \text{as} \quad x \to 0
\end{align}