# Is this proof of limit existence correct?

Tags: limits

So I have to prove the existence of the following: $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{-e^{xy} + 1}{xy}$

First I attempt to find  $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{xy}$, so should this not exist I can assert that the limit does not exist.

Looking at the plot of this function I can see that closing on to the origin the path $y = x$ approaches $\infty$ , and the path $y = -x$ approaches $-\infty$, so I think it's safe to assume that this limit does not exist.

To prove it I write the following:

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x,x)} \frac{1}{xy}=$
$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x,x)} \frac{1}{x^2}=\infty$

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x,-x)} \frac{1}{xy}=$
$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x,-x)} \frac{1}{-x^2}=-\infty$

Is this correct? Most methods usually replace $(x,y)$ with $(x, 0)$, $(x,mx)$, etc. so I had doubts as to whether this would be a valid answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HINT.  Let $z=xy$.  Then, note that for $|z|< 1$, $\frac{1}{1-z}\ge e^z\ge 1+z$$.

Comment: I can see this is related to the squeeze theorem, but where does the $\frac{1}{1-z}\$ come from and what use would it be?

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\lim_{t\to 0}{1 - e^t\over t} = -\exp'(0) = -1.$$
and $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} xy = 0.$
What does this say to you?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I've seen the $\exp'$ operand before.

Comment: $\exp(x)$ is just $e^x$

Answer (score 1):

In [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837), I showed using the limit definition of the exponential function, the fact that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ monotonically increases, and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequality

$$e^z\ge 1+z \tag 1$$

Then, letting $z=-t$, we see from $(1)$ that

$$e^{-t}\ge 1-t\implies e^t \le \frac{1}{1-t} \tag 2$$

for $t<1$.  Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together yields

$$\frac{1}{1-z}\ge e^z\ge 1+z \tag 3$$

Using $(3)$, we have

$$-\frac{1}{1-xy}=\frac{-xy}{xy(1-xy)}\le\frac{1-e^{xy}}{xy}\le\frac{-xy}{xy}=-1$$

Using the squeeze theorem yields the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{1-e^{xy}}{xy}=-1$$