# Limit with radicals

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Solve without the use of L'Hopital

$$\lim\limits_{x\to1}{\frac{\sqrt{2^x+7}-\sqrt{2^{x+1}+5}}{x^3-1}}$$

I multiplied by the conjugate but nothing has changed.

Comment: Use L'Hospital rule

Comment: use l hospital rule

Comment: solved without the use of L'Hopital

Comment: "Nothing happened"? Did you wait for a while for something to happen?

Comment: After you do the conjugate, we basically want the limit of $\frac{2+2^x-2^{x+1}}{x-1}$.  (There is an easy constant involved.) To make it look nicer, change the sign of the top. Let $f(x)=2^{x+1}-2^x$. Then by the definition of the derivative we want $f'(1)$.

Comment: the denominator is always zero

Comment: When you say "solved without the use of L'Hopital", do you mean that you are required to solve it without L'Hopital, or that you have not tried L'Hopital yet?

Answer (score 1):

We can evaluate the limit of interest by using only well-known bounds for the exponential function along with the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).  To that end we proceed.

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{2^x+7}-\sqrt{2^{x+1}+5}}{x^3-1}&=\frac{2-2^x}{\left(\sqrt{2^x+7}+\sqrt{2^{x+1}+5}\right)(x^3-1)}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{-2}{\left(\sqrt{2^x+7}+\sqrt{2^{x+1}+5}\right)(x^2+x+1)}\right)\left(\frac{2^{x-1}-1}{x-1}\right)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{-2}{\left(\sqrt{2^x+7}+\sqrt{2^{x+1}+5}\right)(x^2+x+1)}\right)\left(\frac{e^{(x-1)\log 2}-1}{x-1}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837), I showed that for $|x|<1$, the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$1+x \le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Therefore, we have for $x<1+\frac{1}{\log 2}$

$$\log 2 \le \frac{e^{(x-1)\log 2}-1}{x-1}\le \frac{\log 2}{1-(x-1)\log 2}$$

whereupon invoking the Squeeze Theorem gives

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{e^{(x-1)\log 2}-1}{x-1}=\log 2$$

And finally, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{2^x+7}-\sqrt{2^{x+1}+5}}{x^3-1}=-\frac19 \log 2$$

Comment: just these transformations I did not know

Comment: @Olya12 Which inequalities?

Comment: beginning with $e^x$

Comment: I added a link.