# Limit of $n\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having trouble with this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}n\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)$$

It's supposed to be solvable without using l'Hospital's rule. I'm guessing it's a case for the squeeze theorem, but I'm not exactly sure. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{n+1-2}{n+1}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{-(n+1)}{2}\cdot\frac{-2n}{n+1}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln\left(\left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{-(n+1)}{2}}\right)^{\frac{-2n}{n+1}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln \left(e^{\frac{-2n}{n+1}}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-2n}{n+1}=-2
\end{align}

Comment: How did you come up with the exponent in step 3?

Comment: @JackKrasowsky I added one more line to elaborate it.

Comment: I meant more like what happened between steps 2 and 3

Comment: @JackKrasowsky because $\frac{-(n+1)}{2}\cdot\frac{-2n}{n+1}=n$.

Comment: Of course, but was there any special reason for writing it this way? Does it have a relationship with the argument of the log function?

Comment: @JackKrasowsky I got your question now. Why I did like that was I tried to make the form of $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{\frac1x}$ that is the definition for $e$.

Comment: Right, I see it now! Thanks

Comment: You should probably put the entire argument to $\ln$ inside parenthesis to make it clear that it is the argument that is raised to the power of $n$ and not the result of $\ln$. This got me confused for a while.

Answer (score 3):

You can write
$$
\frac{n-1}{n+1}=\frac{n+1-2}{n+1}=1-\frac{2}{n+1}
$$
so you can also write your limit as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}(n+1)\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}
\ln\biggl(\biggl(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\biggr)^{n+1}\biggr)
$$
Now you should know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(1+\frac{a}{n}\biggr)^n=e^a
$$

Comment: This was helpful too

Answer (score 1):

With equivalents: $\;\ln(1-u)\sim_0 -u$, hence
$$n\ln\Bigl(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\Bigr)=n\ln\Bigl(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\Bigr)\sim_\infty-\frac{2n}{n+1}\sim_\infty -2.$$

Comment: This is too advanced for me I'm afraid

Comment: Didn't you see some asymptotic analysis and Taylor's formula?

Answer (score 1):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837), I showed using standard tools that don't rely on derivatives that, for $z>-1$, the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{z}{z+1}\le \log (1+z)\le z$$

Now, we note that $\log \left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)=\log \left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)$.  Therefore, we have for $n>1$

$$-\frac{2n}{(n-1)}\le n\log \left(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)\le -\frac{2n}{n+1}$$

Using the Squeeze Theorem, we obtain the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\,\log \left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)=-2$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

Notice, let $\frac{1}{n}=t$, hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)$$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{\frac{1}{t}-1}{\frac{1}{t}+1}\right)$$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1-t\right)-\ln\left(1+t\right)}{t}$$
Now, using Taylor's series, 
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^2)\right)-\left(t-\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^2)\right)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(-\left(1+\frac{t}{2}+O(t)\right)-\left(1-\frac{t}{2}+O(t)\right)\right)$$
$$=-\left(1+0\right)-\left(1-0\right)=\color{red}{-2}$$

Comment: What's the O thing supposed to be?

Comment: abbreviation for higher power terms as the series has infinite terms

Comment: Alright, thanks

Comment: Why do you write $\ln\left(1-t\right)-\ln\left(1+t\right)$ as $
-\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^2)\right)-\left(t-\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^2)\right)$ and not just as 
$-\left(t+O(t^2)\right)-\left(t+O(t^2)\right)$? The former is not incorrect and it will lead to the correct answer but it does not make much sense to me. The $\frac{t^2}{2}$ terms have no effect since you have the $O(t^2)$ terms. Besides the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+t)$ around $t=0$ is $t-t^2+...$, not $t-\frac{t^2}{2}+...$.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply one needs to use the standard limit formula $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1\tag{1}$$ We have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(\frac{n - 1}{n + 1}\right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(1 - \frac{2}{n + 1}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}n\cdot\frac{-2}{n + 1}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n + 1}\right)}{-\dfrac{2}{n + 1}}\notag\\
&= -2\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n + 1}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x}\text{ (putting }x = -\frac{2}{n + 1})\notag\\
&= -2\cdot 1\cdot 1 = -2\notag
\end{align}