# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x \ln(16x +14) - (x \ln(16x +7))$ using Maclaurin series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the limit of   $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x \ln(16x +14)  - (x \ln(16x +7))$.

I know I have to use Maclaurin series, but something went wrong.

Comment: $\displaystyle x\ln(16x+14)-x\ln(16x+7)=x\ln\left(\frac{16x+14}{16x+7}\right)=x \ln \left(1+ \frac{7}{16x+7} \right)=\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{7}{16x+7}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$. Now you can use L'hopital/Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+t)$. Good luck.

Comment: But, If I want to solve it by Maclaurin in the begginging.
I would get 2 Polynomials with the same high pow.
Can you help me with this ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have the you tried replacing $16x+7$ with $u$, expanding the logarithms, and then canceling? Using a substitution could reduce errors. You could always do it from that start though.. What is the expansion of the natural logarithm

Comment: Edit your question to include your expansions so we can check them

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any series expansion or L'Hospital to find this limit. You need only the continuity of $\ln(x)$ and some arithmetics:

\begin{gather}\lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln (16x+14) - x\ln(16x+7) =\\= \lim_{x \to \infty} x\ln\left({{16x+14}\over{16x+7}}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln\left(\left({{16x+14}\over{16x+7}}\right)^x\right) =\\ 
= \lim_{x \to \infty} \ln\left(\left({{16x+14}\over{16x+7}}\right)^x\right) = \ln\left(\lim_{x \to \infty}\left({{16x+14}\over{16x+7}}\right)^x\right) =\\= \ln\left(\lim_{x \to \infty}\left({{1+{14\over {16x}}}\over{1+{7\over {16x}}}}\right)^x\right) =  \ln\left({{e^{14 \over 16}}\over{e^{7\over 16}}}\right)
= \ln\big({e^{7\over 16}}\big)  =  {7\over 16} \end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

**METHODOLOGY $1$: Non-Calculus Based**

We can evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x\log(16x+14)-x\log(16x+7)\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{8x}\right)-x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{16x}\right)\right)\tag 1$$

using only a standard inequality and the Squeeze Theorem.

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837), and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x}{1+x}\le \log (1+x)\le x \tag 2$$

using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality.

Applying $(2)$ to the right-hand side of $(1)$ reveals

$$x\left(\frac{\frac7{8x}}{1+\frac7{8x}}\right)-x\frac{7}{16x}\le x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{8x}\right)-x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{16x}\right)\le x\left(\frac{7}{8x}\right)-x\left(\frac{\frac7{16x}}{1+\frac7{16x}}\right)$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac7{16}\left(\frac{1-\frac{7}{8x}}{1+\frac{7}{16x}}\right)\le x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{8x}\right)-x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{16x}\right)\le \frac7{16}\left(\frac{1+\frac{7}{8x}}{1+\frac{7}{16x}}\right) \tag 3$$

Finally, applying the Squeeze Theorem to $(3)$ yields the result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x\log(16x+14)-x\log(16x+7)\right)=\frac{7}{16}}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:  Series Expansion**

If one wishes to use a series expansion, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{8x}\right)-x\log\left(1+\frac{7}{16x}\right)\right)&=\left(\frac78 +O\left(\frac1x\right)\right)-\left(\frac7{16}+O\left(\frac1x\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac7{16}+O\left(\frac1x\right)\\\\
&\to \frac{7}{16}\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty
\end{align}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If you don't find it useful, then I am happy to delete it.  - Mark

Comment: Noam.  Shall I delete my answer then?  - Mark