# Limit $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log{x}}{x-1}$ without L'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was wondering if it's possible to identify this limit without using L'Hôpital's Rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log{x}}{x-1}$$

Comment: Note that $\log 1 = 0$, so you are evaluating $\log'$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Since this is precisely the limit of the difference quotient that defines the derivative of $\log x$ at $x=1$, it might motivate your Readers a little to know why you want to avoid l'Hôpital in this situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837) I showed, without the use of calculus, that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1$$

Therefore, we can write for $x>1$

$$\frac1x \le \frac{\log(x)}{x-1}\le 1$$

and for $x<1$

$$1 \le \frac{\log(x)}{x-1}\le \frac1x$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yields the result $1$.

Comment: An elegant one!

Comment: @LaurentDuval Laurent.  Thank you!  Much appreciated. - Mark

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on copper.hat's comment, it does **not** require L'Hopital's rule to recognize that

$$\lim_{x\to1}{\log x\over x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}{\log x-\log1\over x-1}=f'(1)\quad\text{where }f(x)=\log x$$

This is simply the *definition* of the derivative.  If you also know that $f'(x)=1/x$, then you get

$$\lim_{x\to1}{\log x\over x-1}=1$$

It might be noted that L'Hopital's rule is often invoked for problems like this, but its invocation is *purely a matter of convenience*.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite this using $t = h-1$ as $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\log(1+t) - 0}{t}.$$

Now try to recognize this as the derivative of a function you know.

The point of this exercise is almost certainly to recognize that this *is* the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log{x}}{x-1}$$
$$=\lim_{(x-1) \to 0} \frac{\log{[1+(x-1)]}}{(x-1)}$$
$$=\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\log{(1+u)}}{u}$$
$$= \log'(0)$$
$$=1$$

The last step comes from [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Logarithmic_and_exponential_functions).

Comment: why is the last step obvious -- you have a 0/0 form?

Comment: This is the derivative of $u\mapsto \ln(1+u)$ at $0$. I.e., $\frac{1}{1+0}=1$.

Comment: @gt6989b It's a common limit used often.

Comment: Think you mean $\log^{'} 1$

Comment: It's curious that you posted an answer and voted to close the post.  ;-))

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to avoid relying on knowing derivatives already, you can write $\frac{\log x}{x-1}=\frac{\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}}{x-1}$, showing it to be the mean value of $\frac{1}{t}$ for $t\in[1,x]$. Take $x\to1$ to show that the limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: Well, the use of integrals kind of embeds derivatives through the FTC, does it not? ;-) - Mark

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Decompose the logarithm into Taylor series around $1$.

Comment: Umm, this avoids l'Hôpital (one derivative) by taking derivatives of all orders?

Comment: @hardmath you only need up to the quadratic term. The OP was not interested in minimizing the number of derivatives, just in avoiding to use L'Hospital's rule...

Comment: I will let the OP speak for what they wanted to avoid, but to me (see my Comment) it appears the request was to avoid taking any derivatives.  So when a number of answers are proposed to use the Taylor series instead, I'm not sure it is in the spirit of the Question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log{x}}{x-1}\quad\iff\quad\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}$$

Using Taylor expansion we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-x^2/2+O(x^3)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}(1-x/2+O(x^2))=1$$

Comment: BTW, you don't need the quadratic term, only $x+o(x)$.

Comment: This is l'Hospital's rule, just thinly wrapped as Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Area]

From the above image it is easy to observe that,
 $$\frac{x-1}{x}<\int^{x}_{1}t dt<x-1$$

Since Area of smaller rectangle< Area under curve< Area of larger rectangle,

$$\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}<\frac{log(x)}{x-1}<1$$

$lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{x}=1$

Hence by Sandwich Theorem $lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{log(x)}{x-1}=1$

Comment: Those inequalities for the logarithm can be established without the use of calculus.  ;-)  - Mark