# Find $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac {x-1}{\log_e x} $

Tags: limits

:$$ L= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac {x-1}{\log_e x} $$

Let $ x = h + 1, h = x - 1. $ as $ x \to 1,  h \to 0$

$$L = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h} {\log_e (h+1)}$$

here we have a formula
 $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1 $$
can i use it here!?

Comment: yes, you can use it.

Comment: Shouldnt it be $ln$ as after change of base you can put $e$ as base

Comment: I changed your title to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

Its just $$\frac{1}{\frac{log_e(1+h)}{h}}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$

Comment: you divided num and denominator by h right?

Comment: No just took h down nothing more

Comment: are we allowed to do that?

Comment: Its basic algebra why not

Comment: Dividing numerator and denominator by $h$ would give the same expression

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$ by taking inverse as follows $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{\log(h+1)}=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}\right)^{-1}=\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}\right)^{-1}=(1)^{-1}=\color{red}{1}$$

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be instructive to present another way forward.

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837) I showed, without the use of calculus, that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1$$

for $x>0$.  Therefore, we can write for $x>1$

$$1 \le \frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\le x$$

and for $0<x<1$

$$x \le \frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\le 1$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yields the result $1$.