# Evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} (\ln\ x)^{x-1}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

Evaluate:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} (\ln\ x)^{x-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le\log(x)\le x-1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837), I showed using only (i) the limit definition of the exponential function and (ii) Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le\log(x)\le x-1$$for $x>0$.  Therefore, we can write $$\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{x-1}\le\left(\log(x)\right)^{x-1}\le (x-1)^{x-1} \tag 1$$Using the well-known result $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$ we see that $\lim_{x\to 1^+}(x-1)^{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{x-1}=1$.  Applying the squeeze theorem to $(1)$ yields $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\log(x)\right)^{x-1}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Take logs to get $(x-1)\ln \ln x$ and use L'Hospital's Rule after a minor transformation.