# Solving limit shape $0^0$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I have an exercise which is $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x$.

I have done it, and the answer is $1$, but I just need to know the easiest way to solve it without l'Hospital's rule, since in my country they don't allow us to use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Use of l'Hospital's rule is punishable by five years in prison.

Comment: By the way, $0^0$ is a loosely notation because it is a confusion between two very different cases : First : $\lim_{x \to 0^+} (x^x)$ and second : $\lim_{  \begin{cases} x \to 0^+ \\ y \to 0 \end{cases} } (x^y)\quad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$**

Here is one way to evaluate the limit without use of L'Hospital's Rule.  We make use of the inequality

$$e^x\ge \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n \tag 1$$

for $x>-n$, which I proved in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) using only the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality.  Note that setting $n=2$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$e^x\ge 1+x+\frac14x^2 \tag 2$$

for $x>-2$.

Proceeding with the evaluation of the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x$, we note that we can write $x^x=e^{x\log(x)}$.  Next, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log(x)&=-\lim_{x\to \infty}xe^{-x}\\\\
&=-\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x}
\end{align}$$

From $(2)$, we find that the term $\frac{x}{e^x}$ satisfies the inequalities

$$0\le \frac{x}{e^x}\le \frac{x}{1+x+\frac14x^2} \tag 3$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem to $(3)$ reveals

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0$$

Finally, since $e^0=1$, we find the limit of interest is indeed

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}x^x=1$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$**

Alternatively, I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig/1446837#1446837), using only the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality, that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{z-1}{z}\le \log(z)\le z-1 \tag 4$$

Setting $z=x^\mu$, $\mu<1$ in $(4)$ yields

$$\frac{x^\mu -1}{\mu x^\mu}\le \log(x)\le \frac{x^\mu -1}{\mu}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\frac{x(1-x^{-\mu})}{\mu}\le x\log(x)\le \frac{x(x^\mu -1)}{\mu} \tag 5$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem to $(5)$ yields

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log(x)=0$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $0 < x < 1$ we have the inequality $1-x < -\ln x < (1-x)/x.$

Hence,

$$2x (1- \sqrt{x}) < -x\ln x = -2x\ln \sqrt{x} < \frac{2x(1-\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Applying the squeeze theorem we have $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln x = 0$ and using the continuity of the exponential function

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x^x = \lim_{x \to 0}\exp(\ln x^x)=\lim_{x \to 0}\exp(x\ln x)=\exp(\lim_{x \to 0}x \ln x)= 1.$$

Comment: This is the way forward that I originally was going to present.  Of course, one might ask how the bounds for the logarithm were obtained.  You might consider showing this using either the integral definition of the logarithm or use my approach for the bounds on the exponential function.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks for the tip.  I would hope this is considered a well-known result in the vein of $\ln(1+x) < x$.  The crucial $x \ln x \to 0$ is the essence of this problem.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Do you think that the inequality $\log(1+x)\le x$ is any better known than the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$?  ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Whew, this was harder than I thought.  Hopefully someone will provide a shorter answer.  Instead of showing that $x^x$ tends to $1$, you can instead show that $\ln(x^x) = x \ln(x)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$ from the right.

The derivative of $x \ln x$ is $h(x) = \ln x + 1$, and so for $x > 0$, $$ x \ln x = \int_1^x (\ln t + 1)dt - 1 \cdot \ln(1) = \int_1^x (\ln t + 1)dt$$  Now, you need to show that the area under the curve from $0$ to $1$ of $h(x)$ is $0$.  If you draw a picture, you can instead consider the area vertically rather than horizontally, by integrating the inverse of $h$, which is $g(x) = e^{x-1}$.

Geometrically, you can see that $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{e}} (\ln t + 1)dt = -\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{t-1}dt = -\frac{1}{e}$$ and similarly $$1 = \int_{\frac{1}{e}}^1 (\ln t + 1)dt + \int_0^1 e^{t-1}dt = \int_{\frac{1}{e}}^1 (\ln t + 1)dt + \frac{e-1}{e}$$ so $\int_{1/e}^1 (\ln t + 1)dt = 1 - \frac{e-1}{e} = \frac{1}{e}$.  Thus $$\int_0^1 (\ln t + 1)dt = -\frac{1}{e} + \frac{1}{e} = 0$$ as required.

Comment: if any of the equalities with the integrals are unclear to you, draw the graph of the function $y = \ln x + 1$ and all will become clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather against the law and use l'hospital rule instead