# Find a limit without l'Hospital: $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(2^x + 1)}{\ln(3^x+ 1)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(2^x + 1)}{\ln(3^x+ 1)}\right)$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(2^x + 1)}{\ln(3^x+ 1)}\right)$ = 
 $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{\ln2^x + \ln(1+\frac{1}{2^x})}{\ln3^x + \ln(1+\frac{1}{3^x})}\right)$ = 
 $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{\ln2^x + \frac{1}{2^x}\ln(1+\frac{1}{2^x})^{2^{x}}}{\ln3^x + \frac{1}{3^x}\ln(1+\frac{1}{3^x})^{3^{x}}}\right)$ = $\cdots$

This method is not working.

Comment: Hint: Make a graph. At least you get an idea that probably you wouldn't have to go into an algebraic forest

Comment: When $x \to -\infty$, then $2^x \to 0$. Look at $\ln (1 + z)$ for $z$ near $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer But then i have $\lim_{x \to - \infty} \frac{0}{0}$

Comment: But you know (roughly) _how fast_ the numerator and the denominator tend to $0$.

Comment: I don't understand. Could You explain?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446831/find-lim-limitsx-to-infty-frac-ln-left13x-right-ln-left12x-rig

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 7 questions in past two days. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If we use the well known  limit

$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+X)}{X}=1$$

with $X=2^x\;$ and $\;X=3^x,\;\;$we find

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^x=+\infty$$

Comment: Sharp answer +1

Comment: Hahaha, no American slang.. Your answer only took few lines, which is great!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\ln(1+t)=t+o(t^2). 
$$
Thus, since $2^x\to0$ and $3^x\to0$ when $x\to-\infty$, 
$$
\frac{\ln(1+2^x)}{\ln(1+3^x)}=\frac{2^x+o(2^{2x})}{3^x+o(3^{2x})}
=\left(\frac23\right)^x\,\frac{1+o(2^x)}{1+o(3^x)}.
$$
The second fraction goes to $1$ when $x\to-\infty$. So the limit will be equal to 
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac23\right)^x=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\exp\left(x\ln\left(\frac23\right)\,\right)=+\infty.
$$